# How can I force knitr to input a tikzpicture directly?

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown, knitr, tikz

My aim is to produce a document by mixing hand-written .tex files and .tex files generated from an Rmarkdown file using knitr with figures rendered as tikzpicture.

How do I achieve the generated .tex file to simply contain

```
\begin{figure}
  \input{unnamed-chunk-1-1.tex}
\end{figure}
```

I am struggling with tikz as device. I tried the `tikzDevice` library as well as `knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev="tikz")` I managed to create a .tex file with a tikzpicture environment for every chunk. Unfortunately knitr rendered said .tex file to pdf and generated an `\includegraphics` command. The most annoying problem with that is, I need to copy-paste my header into `options(tikzLatexPackages)` redundantly or "TeX is unable to calculate metrics".

Additionally I did not manage to put the graphics into a `figure` environment. If I simply enclose the chunk with `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}`, it will not include the pdf at all anymore and replace the command with `![](figures/unnamed-chunk-1-1.pdf)<!-- -->`.

After going through the Rmarkdown documentation, I tried setting the chunkoption `external=TRUE`, but that had  no effect.

EDIT: The environment should be generated when setting the chunk option `fig.env='figure'`, but like `external=TRUE`, that had no effect on the generated .tex file.