# How can I knit a .Rnw-file into latex, with plots as tikzpicture environments? (error: formal argument matched by multiple actual arguments)

Tags: r, latex, knitr, tikzdevice

I'm trying to convert a .Rnw document to latex (to be included in another .tex-document). All plots are generated using the `tikz` device, but each of them as a standalone document. My goal is to have them in `tikzpicture` environments.

### Solution attempt

According to the [knitr documentation on plots](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#plots), it should be possible to pass `standAlone=FALSE` via the `dev.args`-list. This produces the error message `formal argument "standAlone" matched by multiple actual arguments`. Knitr issue [#514](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/514) describes the same error message, but their solution doesn't work here.

To reproduce, run `knitr::knit("mwe.Rnw")` on the following file:

```
\section*{MWE}
<<echo=FALSE,dev="tikz",dev.args=list(standAlone=FALSE)>>=
plot(x=1:10)
@
```

Error message:

```
Quitting from lines 3-4 (mwe.Rnw) 
Error in tikzDevice::tikz(..., packages = c("\n\\nonstopmode\n", packages,  : 
  formal argument "standAlone" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

According to [tikzDevice documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tikzDevice/vignettes/tikzDevice.pdf), `standAlone=FALSE` should be the default anyway, no idea why this doesn't apply here.

Any help is greatly appreciated. A [seemingly related, but less specific, question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56041034/how-can-i-force-knitr-to-input-a-tikzpicture-directly) has been posted but without answer.

### Setup

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.2

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

knitr_1.27
tikzDevice_0.12.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument `standAlone` is controlled by the chunk option `external`, so what you need is:

```
<<dev="tikz", external=FALSE>>=
```